# How should I retopo an object with multiple cylindrical arch-type structures properly?

Tags: modeling, retopology

This piece is not going to be edited other than UV for textures for baking. Is retopo even necessary on this model?

[image: Without Tr]

[image]

Comment: If there's no pinching, artefacts, etc, you can keep it as it is

Comment: ..and definitely the upper version will be better than the lower version.